# Shopping route optimization algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, vehicle-routing

There are number of shops `s` which offer articles `a` for different prices. It is possible for a shop to not offer a specific product. Shops can be connected to each other (streets).

The task is to find an optimal route (cycle) from (and back to) some home location, so that the total price is minimal. The total prices is the sum of prices of the articles and the sum of the distances between the shops.

The prices of articles are known for each shop. A shop does not need to be visited for this information.

The constraits are:

- The buyer/traveller wants to purchase a list of articles, potentially all articles
- Every article is available at least in one shop
- The distances between shops are expressed as *cost*, so it may be simply added to the cost of the purchased articles, when calculating the total cost of a route
- Shops can be visited more than once, but that would increase the travelling an therefore the total cost of a route

---

I did the initial modeling with [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/), modeling the shops (and the home) as a directed graph (with the distance/cost as weight), where each node (shop) holds a list of all prices for the products it offers.

My first attempt was to create a brute-force solution, and I succeeded by iterating over all [simple cycles](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html). Then, for each cycle I calculate the travelling costs and the costs of the articles (that is, the minimum prices, as they appear in the shops of the cycle).

Now the above works, but doesn't scale: The time complexity for enumerating all cycles is `O((n+e)(c+1))` for n nodes, e edges and c elementary circuits ([Finding all the elementary circuits of a directed graph. D. B. Johnson, SIAM Journal on Computing 4, no. 1, 77-84, 1975](http://epubs.siam.org/sicomp/resource/1/smjcat/v4/i1/p77_s1)). And the number of cycles (circuits) grows quite rapidly:

```
# random 'streetlike' shop-graphs

number of shops: 3, cycles: 2
number of shops: 4, cycles: 11
number of shops: 5, cycles: 11
number of shops: 6, cycles: 60
number of shops: 7, cycles: 229
number of shops: 8, cycles: 868
number of shops: 9, cycles: 1399
number of shops: 10, cycles: 61139
number of shops: 11, cycles: 60066
number of shops: 12, cycles: 1246579
number of shops: 13, cycles: 7993420
```

Any suggestions for a more scalable problem description? I'm thinking about dynamic or linear programming solutions, but I'd love to hear ideas.

---

update: Found a whole PhD thesis on the topic: ftp://tesis.bbtk.ull.es/ccppytec/cp181.pdf

Comment: Nice question.  But does Python have anything to do with it?

Comment: Sounds easy -- just don't go anywhere, and don't buy anything. Total price is minimized :)

Comment: Are the article availability and price available for lookup, or does one have to visit a store to know the availability and price?

Comment: @BenS All prices are known. A shop does not need to be visited for this information.

Comment: In seriousness, though -- what are the constraints? Do you have to visit every shop? Do you have to purchase one of every article? If you visit a shop, do you have to purchase whatever is in it? Can you re-visit shops on the way back to minimize travel cost? And are you saying that the distance between shops is also expressed in a cost, on the same scale as the cost of the articles?

Comment: @IanClelland, I edited my question a bit. The only contraint is, that the buyer/traveller wants to purchase a list of articles. He may visit shops more than once, but that would only increase the travelling costs, so such solutions would probably fall out. The distances between shops is just a price (which can be added to the article's prices when calculating the total cost of a route).

Comment: it's NP-hard. if you had only one type of product, each shop sold 1 unit, you wanted to buy #of units equal to number of shops, then if you had polynomial solution to this, you'd have solution to TSP. you might want to have a look at [travelling purchaser problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_purchaser_problem), maybe you can adjust the algorithms for solving that one

Comment: Revisiting shops may not increase travel costs -- if you imagine a set of shops in a ring, where the last link (from the last shop back to the home node) is prohibitively expensive, then retracing your steps through previously visited shops might be cheaper than completing the cycle.

Comment: @IanClelland, yes, you're right about that a minimum may include passing though a shop node more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more information - if the total 'cost' is the distance traveled plus the amount of money spent then we struggle because they arn't the same units - so if distance is cheap then this becomes an instance of the traveling salesman problem - identify the lowest cost item of each time and then compute the route to get them all, if distance is expensive compared to the cost of the item, then we have different problem.

Summary - I think this problem will be complete if you add the constaint - each mile traveled costs $R$ units of money, then we can start building solutions...

Comment: I added some clarification to the question (hopefully). The distance between shops and the purchase prices are in the same *dimension*. The costs between nodes are know and could be expressed, e.g. as weights on edges.

Comment: Ah-ha - that's much clearer now - though I think Ian's Answer is exactly what you are looking for...

Comment: Joe, you need to work on the quality of your answers.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer.

Comment: Hi Robert - will do... can you give me a bit more specific feedback? If I'm being rude I apologise, it's certainly not my intention :(